# Doubly linked explicit list

Tags: list, data-structures, malloc

When using explict lists for a memory allocator, why do the lists have to be doubly linked? Can an explicit list memory allocator be singly linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been answered in this question: [Malloc Allocation Schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005436/malloc-allocation-schemes) (...so it is not a must to make a doubly linked list, but it makes a life bit easier)